# Third-party services used in the Microsoft Outlook Add-in

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, outlook, lightning-for-outlook

While reading the description of the Salesforce Outlook Add-In (available [here](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en/product/office/WA104379334?tab=Overview)), I noticed that:

> This add-in can read or modify the contents of any item in your
>   mailbox, and create new items. It can access personal information --
>   such as the body, subject, sender, recipients, or attachments -- in
>   any message or calendar item. It may send this data to a third-party
>   service.

Does anyone know which third-party service are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1):

"Third-party" is relative to the publisher of Outlook: Microsoft. In this case, Microsoft is asserting that the add-in can send data to Salesforce.